# How to left align elements in a jqmath table

Tags: javascript, jqmath

If I try to create a table in [jqmath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html), it always centers the elements.  So if I write

```
$$\table a , b ; c , dddddddddddd ;$$
```

then I get

```
a          b
c    dddddddddddd
```

How do I make jqmath align the columns to the left, so that the table is displayed as

```
a    b
c    dddddddddddd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is style the appropriate tags.

```
<style type="text/css">
mtd, .fm-mtd  {
    text-align:left;
}
</style>
```

This is demonstrated in the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/creemama/ehbLt/3/).

To find out more about how to style code generated by jqMath, just look at their [CSS style sheet](http://mathscribe.com/mathscribe/jqmath-0.2.0.css).

jqMath behaves differently on differing browsers. By default, Chrome displays the text using left alignment, whereas Firefox displays the text using center alignment. Chrome uses `<td class="fm-mtd">` while Firefox uses `<mtd>`. The tag used depends upon whether the [web browser supports MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML#Web_browsers).

To learn more about `text-align`, visit the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align).

Comment: Thanks, but Firefox and Chrome display it differently.  Firefox shows your example centered, while Chrome correctly left-aligns it.  Is there a work around for that?