# Is it possible to style jqmath - display with another font, on webpages

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, google-webfonts, jqmath

I previously used mathjax to generate math on a website. It was not possible for me to style mathjax, which made the design awful (website had one font, and mathjax came with another font (stix).

Is JQ Math a good alternative?, and it is possible to style the output from jqmath to match the font that i use on the website?

Answer (score 2):

Just use normal CSS to override any rules in jqmath-0.2.0.css after loading that file, e.g.:

```
math, fmath, .fm-math, fmath mo, .fm-mo, .ma-sans-serif
    { font-family: McLaren, 'Cantora One', sans-serif }
```

See [How to left align elements in a jqmath table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965767/how-to-left-align-elements-in-a-jqmath-table) and [jqMath highlight box like bbox in MathJax/MathJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805054/jqmath-highlight-box-like-bbox-in-mathjax-mathjs) for more jqMath CSS examples and information.