# How to increase font size of jqMath equation for Android app

Tags: javascript, android, jqmath

So here's my code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.layout_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String js = "<html><head>"
       + "<link rel='stylesheet' href='file:///android_asset/mathscribe/jqmath-0.4.0.css'>"
       + "<script src = 'file:///android_asset/mathscribe/jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>"
       + "<script src = 'file:///android_asset/mathscribe/jqmath-etc-0.4.2.min.js'></script>"
       + "</head><body>"
       + "<script>var s =   '$$x={-b±√{b^2-4ac}}/{2a}$$';M.parseMath(s);document.write(s);</script> </body>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", js, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Even though I set the fontsize to 100 the equation doesn't change in size at all no matter what number I set in the font size. Is there a way to increase the font size of the equation?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where and when you set the font size to 100 (as it is not apparent in the code you posted).

According to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12189013/1387346) you should set the font size **after** loading `jqmath-x.y.css` in order to override the values it contains.

Try setting it in the JavaScript after the code you posted. Something like `document.body.style.fontSize = "100pt";` after your `document.write` for example.

```js
var s = '$$x={-b±√{b^2-4ac}}/{2a}$$';
M.parseMath(s);
document.write(s);
document.body.style.fontSize = "40pt";
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mathscribe.com/mathscribe/jqmath-0.4.0.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mathscribe.com/mathscribe/jqmath-etc-0.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. It increases the font size of the "x=" but not the rest.

Here's the updated code:

+ "<script>var s = '$$x={-b±√{b^2-4ac}}/{2a}$$';M.parseMath(s);document.body.style.fontSize = \"20pt\";document.write(s); </script></body>";

Comment: Well it works fine in a browser, but I can't exactly test it in an Android project as you have it.